# dlinq versus ADO.NET Entity Framework

Tags: web-applications, ado.net, dynamic-linq

I am about to finalize the design of my webapplication, i am building it as an n-tier architecture and i am posed with the question of using DLinq vs EFM. I would appreciate if  someone could give me some expert advice on it.

Answer (score 1):

One suggested question I would ask, "How big (table count) is your database?"  The more tables you have, the less friendly linq becomes and the more you'll want a more robust ORM that let's you build custom mappings.